# Asp.net core dosn't change the CultureInfo

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, webapi

- The first time i call the method with "en-GB"
  then test2 is en-GB.
- The Second time i call the method, test is till Russian, how can i fix this issue?

```
services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
{
    var defaultCulture = new CultureInfo("ru-RU");
    var englishCulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
    var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
    {
        defaultCulture,
        englishCulture
    };
    options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(defaultCulture,defaultCulture);
    options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
    options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;

    var defaultCookieRequestProvider = options.RequestCultureProviders
        .FirstOrDefault(rcp => rcp.GetType() == typeof(CookieRequestCultureProvider));
    if (defaultCookieRequestProvider != null)
        options.RequestCultureProviders.Remove(defaultCookieRequestProvider);

    options.RequestCultureProviders
        .Insert(0,
        new CookieRequestCultureProvider()
        {
            CookieName = CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName,
            Options = options
        });
});
```

and i have

```
            var options = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
            app.UseRequestLocalization(options.Value);
```

Controller - The second time it will be called it still will be Russian instead of English

```
public async Task ChangeLocalization([FromBody] LocalizationDto inDto)
{
    var test = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture;
    var settedCulture = new CultureInfo(inDto.CurrentCultureName);
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = settedCulture;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = settedCulture;
    if (HttpContext.Request.Cookies.ContainsKey(CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName))
            HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Delete(CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName);

    HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append(
        CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName,
        CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(
            new RequestCulture(settedCulture, settedCulture)));

    var test2 = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture;
}
```

Does the same issue:

```
 Response.Cookies.Append(
                CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName,
                CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(new RequestCulture(settedCulture)),
                new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.CookieOptions { Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddYears(1) });
```

**Solved by adding:
this.httpClient.defaults.headers["Accept-Language"] = "en-GB";
to vue js**

Comment: Could be that, by default, cookies are not sent to browser until cookie consent is accepted. Workaround would be to mark language cookie essential.

Comment: How can i do it?
I'm using also a vue js to call this method

Comment: Response.Cookies.Append(
                CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName,
                CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(new RequestCulture(settedCulture)),
                new CookieOptions
                {
                    Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddYears(1),
                    IsEssential = true,  //critical settings to apply new culture
                    Path = "/",
                    HttpOnly = false,
                }
            );

Comment: have tried that and it's not working

Comment: Could you pls adding your solution as the answer but not adding it in your question to end up this case? Many thanks sir .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding:

```
this.httpClient.defaults.headers["Accept-Language"] = "en-GB";
```

to vue js - Using axios!